# Can we encourage users not to leave comments on decade old questions and answers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

More specifically, if the question is on a niche topic (e.g. asm/kernel stuff), has low number of up/down votes, few/no/unaccepted answers, low number of views, wouldn't it be
nice to notify a future user **not** to leave comments/answers (very likely, waste their time)?

Comment: What's the actual harm without that feature??

Comment: Wasted time; both on their side and the poster's.

Comment: I'm usually just ignoring to check notifications from my inbox based on the short text. I rarely waste time about such comments, and even if some I believe such feature would be counter productive all over.

Comment: I don't understand why would we want to do that. If someone feels that a comment is needed then they should add the comment regardless of the post's age.

Comment: But it's hard to see the point of adding the comment. Who will benefit from it? It really has no value, other than, maybe, lay down the commenter's line of thought.  The q/a then gets bumped and more people will waste time over it.

Comment: leaving a comment doesn't bump a post

Comment: @rene alright; didn't know that :P

Comment: This suggestion does more harm than good. What if the information is out of date and the comment helps to update and improve it? Who is to judge if a comment is helpful or not, and how is it to be judged? I urge to decline this suggestion.

Comment: The point of adding the comment is to convey information to other people viewing it. The criticism offered in the comment can be addressed by the author via an edit, but it doesn't need to be.

Comment: @Dharman Who mentioned anything about criticism? Why is there always an undertone of negativity on here (see downvotes)?  It's really as simple as having common courtesy for the commenter's time as well as the askers.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Why? What's the harm in urging people not to waste their time on a very specific niche problem that's no longer relevant for years?

Comment: I didn't mean negativity. I mentioned criticism because it's unlikely you started this topic about comments asking for clarifications. Criticism can be positive too.

Comment: Why do you say the problem is no longer relevant? What makes it irrelevant now?

Comment: @Sebi: again, you assume that most of the comments are on *"very specific niche problem that's no longer relevant..."* -- and I ask, how do you know, how is the site to know that this is so? Who is to judge and by what mechanism do we judge? And even if this is judged true for 80% of questions obtained by some criteria, then your suggestions risks harm by reducing potential beneficial comments to a significant number of questions. It makes no sense.

Comment: Without specifics, the answer is always *"it depends"*.

Comment: @Sebi Well, just to be blunt: That's a silly idea, which would waste precious dev time for nothing gained, and even harm the sites evolvement to get better,.

Comment: "*Why is there always an undertone of negativity on here (see downvotes)*" [downvotes on meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) can also mean just a simple disagreement, nothing more.

Comment: @Dharman Again, these are assumptions, why do you state criticism as fact? or rather, broaden the set of assumption to include research and links to other resources that might be helpful in writing an answer. The only problem is, that, that's no longer relevant since the question's been asked more than 10 years ago.

Comment: > Why do you say the problem is no longer relevant? What makes it irrelevant now?

It was hardly relevant then; using mmx regs to speed up sorting :D

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels 

> you assume that most of the comments are on "very specific niche problem that's no longer relevant..." -- and I ask, how do you know, how is the site to know that this is so?

Alright; let's try to clarify what niche means; because of the inherent limits of the comment section, let's leave it at an example: use llvm to modify the backend of a C compiler to introduce nop instructions to reduce the chances of rop.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Most developers, users that stick around to SO, are, well, average, and therefore highly unlikely to bring any sort of meaningful contributions to these kinds of questions. Why waste their time?

Comment: @PeterMortensen See above comments.

Comment: @AndrewT Correct, except that some users decided to downvote questions on my profile at random.

Comment: @Sebi: but many SO users aren't average, and so let's not throw the baby out with the bathwater. I think that on this subject we're going to have to agree to disagree, but it looks like you are in the minority opinion, for whatever it's worth.

Comment: No, most certainly not, but what is correct or incorrect in this case doesn't really matter. We the community can't really make the SO Team work on this feature, and it seems like a feature they'd never touch anyway. Locking a post from being commented on *because it's old* is counter-productive to keeping content quality on the site high.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels By the looks of it, most are below that. How can someone who spends a good portion of their time on this board not be average? > but it looks like you are in the minority opinion, for whatever it's worth Wait, so the majority's opinion is (always?) correct?

Comment: @Kevin B. How is saving someone's time counterproductive? It wouldn't be too much programming effort to block users from commenting on old posts, anyway.

Comment: Whos time does it save? it doesn't cost the commenter any time to leave a comment that they feel is necessary, it doesn't cost the answerer any time to not read a comment they don't care about, it can *save* time of others who read the comment and determine from the comment that the answer isn't good for a given reason,

Comment: @Kevin B Though anecdotical, some comments have links pointing to code that's no longer relevant (nor would have it been back then) clearly showing some degree of effort.

Comment: that's fine, the cases where they're helpful far outweigh the minor inconvenience. The cases where they aren't, a single flag is generally enough to deal with it.

Answer (score 11):

On a typical Thursday in October 19,097 comments are posted by users with [that privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). The majority of those comments are on recent posts but the drop-off for comments on older posts is dramatic:

[image]
<sup>*Click image for SEDE query*</sup>

And this shows all posts. If you would only look at "niche tags" (*exact definition pending*) you would find even less comments.

So we're now looking at spending dev time on adding a feature for a few occurrences where the benefit of the feature is marginal at best. You could even argue that *not* having recent comments that point out issues on such posts  is doing a disservice to the visitors of that Q/A.

As leaving comments doesn't bump old posts, given most comments aim at improving the quality of the post and the low number of instances you want this feature for I take a stand and propose to **not** implement this feature.

Comment: This will not include comments that were deleted again on that same day. Not much we can do about that though, and also I don't think it would skew the numbers by a lot.